# Access Data from Azure Application Inside

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have created an Azure Function that has the purpose of generating data under certain conditions. During the day, the function is triggered several times and if the condition is met, the data is saved in a database and a project team is informed.
Since it can sometimes happen that no data is generated in a week, the project team should receive a weekly report about the number of Azure Function executions and whether they were successful or not. I have seen in the Azure Portal that the Application Inside stores exactly this data, but I am not yet clear how I can access this data.

What options do I have in Java to retrieve and process the telemetry data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What options do I have in Java to retrieve and process the telemetry data?

**To retrieve the telemetry data and store it for longer time or to process the telemetry data in some specialized way, [Continuous Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry#continuous-export-advanced-storage-configuration) is ideal for this purpose**.

---

Alternative ways to **retrieve** or **access**/**process** the telemetry data:

1. In the Log explorer, export button lets you transfer tables and charts to an Excel spreadsheet.
2. **[Log Analytics Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-query-overview)** also exports the results of telemetry data.
3. [**Power BI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi) used to explore and export your data.
4. To access your telemetry programmatically, you can use the **[Data access REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/overview)**.
5. **[Through PowerShell, you can also access setup continuous export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.applicationinsights/new-azapplicationinsightscontinuousexport?view=azps-7.3.2)**.

---

Instead of **[Log Analytics API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/overview#log-analytics-api-query-limits)**, you can access it programmatically for retrieve and storing the Telemetry data because the Query API has some query limits.

**To access programmatically, the Azure Monitor Query SDK contains idiomatic client libraries for JavaScript, .NET, Python, and Java.**

Refer to the **[Azure Monitor Query Client Library for Java Documentation by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/monitor-query-readme?view=azure-java-stable)** provides sample code examples to view how to access/process the Telemetry logs programmatically.